# good R package for vectorized option pricing

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, r, black76

I am using for now the package `fOptions` but it doesn't allow for vectorized computation of black76 prices and delta.
Which package can be used to do that?

As noted by @Richard, I could use `lapply`, but it is actually looping in R, which is slow (at least too slow for me). I am looking for a package that has a compiled loop, ie that provides a native vectorized function.

Comment: what do you mean by vectorized? Getting price and delta with one function call? Or getting the price for a bunch of options with one call?

Comment: @Richard getting the price for a bunch of options with one call, or getting the delta for a bunch of options with one call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question as it could be useful for others.
Actually package `fOptions` is vectorized. The only constraint (and that make sense) is that you can't compute at the same time 2 different greeks, or mix up calls and puts.

So assuming that you want to compute the delta of a set of puts, the code will be the following:

```
fOptions::GBSGreeks(Selection = "Delta",
                    TypeFlag="p",
                    S=c(100,100)+1:2, 
                    X=c(100,100), 
                    Time=c(0.1,0.2),
                    r=c(0,0), 
                    b=c(0,0), 
                    sigma=c(0.2,0.2))
```

which returns the same (that's the validation) as the output of `mapply`:

```
mapply(FUN       = fOptions::GBSGreeks,
       Selection = c("Delta","Delta"),
       TypeFlag=c("p","p"),
       S=c(100,100)+1:2, 
       X=c(100,100),
       Time=c(0.1,0.2),
       r=c(0,0), 
       b=c(0,0), 
       sigma=c(0.2,0.2))
```

nice...

Answer (score 0):

if you put all your option objects into a list then you can use `lapply`. Read the documentation or just [thist post](https://rollingyours.wordpress.com/category/r-programming-apply-lapply-tapply/) for details.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but `lapply` is actually looping in R, which is slow (at least too slow for me). I am looking for a package that has a compiled loop, ie that provides a native vectorized function.

Comment: I see ... this is different.

Comment: I updated my question to make it more clear

Comment: I stumbled upon this post: http://www.r-bloggers.com/faster-higher-stonger-a-guide-to-speeding-up-r-code-for-busy-people/ there they propose to use the compiler package which can improve speed under some circumstances ...